# Bash - use 1 stop script for multiple similar services, and kill the correct process only

Tags: linux, bash, service

I have multiple processes running as services on a machine
Before moving from 1 process/service to multiple ones, I used the following script to stop my service

```
#!/bin/sh
SIGNAL=${SIGNAL:-TERM}
PIDS=$(ps ax | grep -i 'datastream' | grep java | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}')

if [ -z "$PIDS" ]; then
  echo "No Brooklin server to stop"
  exit 1
else
  kill -s $SIGNAL $PIDS
fi
```

The issue now is that this script kills all processes of this type if invoked as a service stop command

My services are called for example service-A, service-B, service-C. If I send a `service service-C stop` command, the current script will stop all 3 processes.

I would like to make the script use the provided service name to determine which process to stop (I can grep A/B/C from the process output to ps, but I haven't managed to tell it how to stop only the process given in the `service stop` command.

Does anyone have experience handling something similar?

Comment: Try [pgrep or pkill](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below while starting your application which can store your `PID` in a static file and then you can use the same file to kill the process.

Pasting below one of my start - stop script which I have used in past for churning up multiple processes.

Start Script :-

```
#!/bin/bash
export PORT=$1
. /application/setEnv.sh
/java/jdk1.8.0_152/bin/java -Xms512m -Xmx2G -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -jar /application/api-1.0-0-all.jar </dev/null >>$LOGDIR/service$PORT.log 2>&1 &

echo $! > /application/service$PORT.pid

disown $!
```

Stop Script :-

```
#!/bin/bash
PORT=$1
PID=`cat /application/service$PORT.pid`

if [ ! -z "$PID" ]; then
        rm /application/service$PORT.pid
        kill -9 $PID >/dev/null 2>&1
        if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
          echo "PID file found but no matching process was found. Stop aborted."
          exit 1
        fi
      else
        echo "PID file is empty and has been ignored."
fi

mv /application/logs/service$PORT.log /application/logs/service$PORT.log`date +%d%m%Y%H%M%S`
```

Only change which I can think of is the replace my port utilisation logic viz. `$PORT` with your service names viz. A/B/C.